# jQuery Ajax posting Arrays instead of simple data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hey, I've tried to update jQuery to its latest version on a system I'm working and I'm having this issue:

I have a file that posts data to a .php:

```
$.post(

'ajax_Save.php',
{
id: [$('#service_id').val()],
number: [$('#number').val()]
},
    function(data){
...
});
```

On ajax_Save.php var_dump($_POST) gives:

```
array(26) { ["id"]=>  array(1) { [0]=>  string(5) "18204" } ["number"]=>  array(1) { [0]=>  string(5) "18250" }...
```

With jQuery version 1.2.2 the result is:

```
array(26) { ["id"]=>  string(5) "18204" ["order_number"]=>  string(5) "18250"
```

Which is OK.

Any clues? Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace with:

```
$.post(

'ajax_Save.php',
{
id: $('#service_id').val(),
number: $('#number').val()
},
    function(data){
...
});
```

Comment: So stupid of me. I have all my code full with this brackets. Thanks!